# What is the relation between ONVIF profiles and VideoSources?

Tags: c#, camera, video-streaming, onvif

Onvif device manager shows me three profiles for a 4k camera. 
All three have the same Video source configuration with resolution 4000x3000.

All three profiles have different video encoders with resolutions : 3840x2160, 1920x1080, 720x480.

I need to understand the relation between Video source and encoders? which one should I target if I need to change zoom levels?

I want to be able to change video source configuration bounds, not sure how to calculate the new bounds based on zoom levels. Does the encoder resolution have a part to play?

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: What do you mean by "zoom levels"? The zoom is normally set when playing with the ONVIF PTZ Service part and it has been, for the camera I had access to, a value to set between -1.0 and 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in Figure 2 of the [Media Service specifications](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media-Service-Spec.pdf), a media profile may have a PTZ configuration attached to it. You need to check if at least one of the profile has such configuration attached and use the token of that medial profile to move the zoom, according to the [PTZ Service specifications](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/ptz/ONVIF-PTZ-Service-Spec.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

The three profiles will return the same whole image, but in three different resolutions. If you need only a part of the image, you will have to request the first stream, and manually extract the portion from the full resolution image.

However, if you camera is a PTZ, you can move it using ONVIF PTZ functions.